# Logically yet illegaly uninitialized variable in Rust

Tags: enums, rust, refactoring

I'm relatively new to Rust. This question turned out to be pretty long so I'll start with the bottom-line:
*Which solution do you prefer? Do you have any ideas or remarks?*

My code does not compile because lines lines 6 (`prev = curr`) and 12 (`bar(...)`) use variables which the compiler suspects are possibly uninitialized. As the programmer, I know that there is no reason to worry because lines 6 and 12 do not run during the first iteration.

```
let mut curr: Enum;
let mut prev: Enum;

for i in 0..10 {
    if i > 0 {
        prev = curr;
    }

    curr = foo();

    if i > 0 {
        bar(&curr, &prev);
    }
}
```

I understand that there's a limit to what you can expect from a compiler to know. So I came up with 3 different ways to answer the language's safety restriction.

**1) Initialize and stop thinking too much**

I could just initialize the variables with arbitrary values. The risk is that a maintainer might mistakenly think that those initial, hopefully unused, values have some important meaning. Lines 1-2 would become:

```
let mut curr: Enum = Enum::RED; // Just an arbitrary value!
let mut prev: Enum = Enum::BLUE; // Just an arbitrary value!
```

**2) Add `None` value to `Enum`**

Lines 1-2 would become

```
let mut curr: Enum = Enum::None;
let mut prev: Enum = Enum::None;
```

The reason that I dislike this solution is that now I've added a new possible and unnatrural value to my enum. For my own safety, I will have to add assertion checks and match-branches to `foo()` and `bar()`, and any other function that uses `Enum`.

**3) `Option<Enum>`**

I think that this solution is the most "by-the-book" one, but it makes the code longer and harder to comprehend.

Lines 1-2 would become

```
let mut curr: Option<Enum> = None;
let mut prev: Option<Enum> = None;
```

This time, `None` belongs to `Option` and not to `Enum`. The innocent `prev = curr` statement would become

```
prev = match curr {
    Some(_) => curr,
    None => panic!("Ah!")
};
```

and the naive call to `bar()` would uglify to

```
match prev {
    Some(_) => bar(&curr, &prev),
    None => panic!("Oy!")
};
```

**Questions:** Which solution do you prefer? Do you have any ideas or remarks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Where possible, avoid using too many mutable variable bindings in Rust, especially in loops. Managing state within a loop using mutating variables can make code harder to understand and lead to bugs. It's usually a red flag to see a counter variable in a `for` loop, which can very often be replaced with an iterator over values instead.

In your case, you can create an iterator over the values produced by `foo`, and pass them in pairs to `bar`, using `tuple_windows`  from the [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) crate:

```
use itertools::Itertools as _; // 0.9.0
use std::iter::repeat_with;

for (prev, curr) in repeat_with(foo).tuple_windows().take(9) {
    bar(&curr, &prev);
}
```

Note that you can't make a mistake here and forget to set `prev` or `curr`, and future maintainers can't accidentally swap two lines and mess it up either.

This style is very succinct and expressive. For example, the way I've written the snippet above emphasises that `bar` will be called 9 times. You could also modify it slightly if you preferred to emphasise that `foo` will be called 10 times:

```
for (prev, curr) in repeat_with(foo).take(10).tuple_windows() {
    bar(&curr, &prev);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution causes `foo()` to run once more than needed. I'm happy that it's not an issue in my case.

Comment: I still want to skip running `bar()` during the first iteration. How would you do that?

Comment: @JonathanJacobson In your original code, and in both versions suggested in this answer, `foo` is called 10 times and `bar` is called 9 times. Do you mean you want `bar` to only be called 8 times?

Comment: @trentcl what I need is for `bar()` to not run during the first iteration. I found a workaround for that, by encapsulating it inside a struct with "memory" of executions.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson This code iterates one fewer times than the original, which means the `if i > 0` parts in your question are built in to the `tuple_windows` adapter. Are you saying that the code in your question is *incorrect*, and it should actually have said `if i > 1`?

Comment: @trentcl good question. In my case, and I'm not saying that it's some general truth, the `bar()` function needs to not run during the first iteration, or at least know that it is the first iteration. My way of doing so was to skip the first iteration by checking if `i>0`, because in the code that I posted, the first `i` value was `0`. I found now another way of accomplishing this need. Thanks for making me express myself more clearly.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson in the code above, `foo` runs twice before the first time that `bar` runs. It must _must_ do, or else there wouldn't be two values with which to call `bar`. The output of this program is identical to the output of the code in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the logic that you are expressing is what is called a “fold” and you could be using a fold instead of a loop.

What one could do is:

```
(0..9).map(|_|foo()) //an iterator that outputs foo() 9 times, not 10
   .fold(foo(), |prev, curr| {bar(&curr, &prev); curr});
```

The business end is of course the line with `.fold` in it. What a fold does is that it takes a single argument for an initial value, calls a binary function on that initial value and the current value the iterator produces, and then uses the result as the new initial value for the next iteration. I have simply used a function here that is called for the side-effect as you have, and as resulting value use the `curr` value, which is thus used as the initial value of the next iteration, and serves as `prev`.

The final value returned by this expression is the last `curr`, which can of curse be ignored.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold

Answer (score 3):

I am also *very new* to Rust, but I find the third option clearest. I will add that `unwrap()` or `expect()` can be used in place of the match expressions with the same meaning ("I know this is occupied"):

```
let mut curr: Option<Enum> = None;
let mut prev: Option<Enum> = None;

for i in 0..10 {
    if i > 0 {
        prev = curr;
    }

    curr = Some(foo());

    if i > 0 {
        bar(curr.as_ref().unwrap(), prev.as_ref().unwrap());
    }
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=020b631cc029a9d2bad2044e45dbfb8b). It still has a little extra ceremony to it.

Generally I find longer real life examples of loops in this form hard to follow; the structure of the loop obscures the desired logic. If one can structure it more like an iteration, I find it clearer:

```
for (prev, curr) in FooGenerator::new().tuple_windows().take(10) {
    bar(&prev, &curr);
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=83ce1e25bed45e025e82f314577030e9).

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, a simple way of fixing your code is to pull the first iteration out of the loop. Because of the `if` statements, the only thing the first iteration does is calling `foo()`. Additionally, you can move the assignment to `prev` to the end of the loop, so you can scope `curr` to the inside of the loop:

```
let mut prev = foo();
for _ in 1..10 {
    let curr = foo();
    bar(&curr, &prev);
    prev = curr;
}
```

Note that I changed the range to start at 1 instead of 0, since we pulled the first iteration out of the loop.

I don't think this approach is better than the one in the accepted answer, but I do think it's quite simple and easy to understand.